# Get url from java class

Tags: ejb, httprequest

I have this singleton class which will start when the application starts and the method invokes itself for every 30 seconds.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class myClass{
    @Schedule(second="*/30", minute="*", hour="*")
    public void serviceRequest(){
        String url = "";
        //send request
    }
}
```

the url will be something like http://localhost:7001/webapp/rest/tasks/mytask. I don't want to hardcode the url. Instead, I want to somehow get that from the system (or somewhere). I've tried injecting resource like HttpServletRequest but that didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't do it. This is a service layer which should absolutely not be aware of any dependencies from the web layer (like the `javax.servlet` API). Unless you state the functional requirements, this cannot be answered precisely. The service layer should never be dealing with HTTP requests / responses - it should always be independent of its clients - the service layer can be consumed by any clients, not only web clients.

Comment: @Tiny I think this solve my problem lol. The url will be provided by an external service so I dont need to worry about host and port number since ill get full url to that rest service. Because the service isn't available so I made an in house rest service to test my functionality. I guess I will harcode the url for now.

Comment: So you want to fire a HTTP request to own host from inside the EJB? How does that make sense? What exactly is that URL in turn doing? Invoking some other Java class/method? Just change your EJB to invoke exactly that class/method instead of taking a detour via a HTTP request.

Comment: @BalusC I know it doesn't make sense lol. speaking of that, do you think it is a good design to access database through a rest service or just call the DAL derectly?

Comment: If you can directly call it internally, it will of course be (much) more efficient. REST is only useful for public/external access.

Comment: That is what i was thinking. For some reason, people here decided to access in-house database through rest service :( Another problem is that if the request takes too long, the session would expired and no data would returned. :( Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url will be provided by an external service so I dont need to worry about host and port number since ill get full url to that rest service. Because the service isn't available so I made an in house rest service to test my functionality. I guess I will harcode the url for now.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using JAX-RS, then this will work:

```
@RequestScoped @Path("tasks")
public class TaskResource {

    @GET @Path("{id}")
    public Response getTask(@PathParam("id") String id) {
         /* whatever */
    }

}

URI uri = UriBuilder.fromResource(TaskResource.class)
    .segment("{id}").build("mytask");
```

Comment: Sorry I should have explained more. What i need is a way to get localhost and port number because when i deploy this to production environment, the url might be different. For example in development the url might look like http://localhost:7001/rest/tasks/mytask but in production the url might look like http://<host>:<port>/rest/tasks/mytask